# Excel Transpose Like thing

Tags: excel, rows, transpose

I have rows like this:

```
Chris     Chris1     Chris2     Chris3
Jack      Jack1      Jack2      Jack3
Bill      Bill1      Bill2      Bill3
```

Needs to become like this:

```
Chris     Chris1
Chris     Chris2
Chris     Chris3
Jack      Jack1
Jack      Jack2
Jack      Jack3
Bill      Bill1
Bill      Bill2
Bill      Bill3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the TRANSPOSE function.  It must be used as an array formula.  Here is an example:

If you have 5 horizontal cells that need to be vertical, you should select 5 vertical cells.  Then type `=` and `TRANSPOSE(array)`.  `array` is the range of horizontal cells.  Then, type (on your keyboard) `CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER`.  This will make it an array formula.  If it is not an array formula, `TRANSPOSE` will not work.